# .htaccess 301 redirect from non www to www is showing two urls in browser history

Tags: .htaccess

I have made 301 redirect to redirect `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com` with .htaccess,
I have done it this way.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
</IfModule>
```

I have written this code months ago it was working fine till now, but now all of a sudden it is showing two url's in browser history while redirecting properly,

`1st url is http://domain.com`

`2nd url is http://www.domain.com`

I removed the line `Options +FollowSymlinks`, but it still shows two url's.

Please suggest why I am getting two url's in browser history when I should be getting just redirected url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 URLs in your browser history now probably because you've upgraded your browser, changed browser settings, or are using a different browser . The `FollowSymlinks` option doesn't have anything to do with the browser's history. It's to tell the webserver that it is ok to follow symlinks in the directory that the option is turned on in.

The reason why you see both URLs in your browser history is because *you are going to both URLs*.

When you go to `http://domain.com`, your browser sends a resolves the `domain.com` host, then sends a request to that host. The response it gets back is essentially "*what you are looking for is not here, go to `http://www.domain.com` instead, and continue to go there the next time you are looking for `http://domain.com`*". The browser then processes the request for `http://www.domain.com`, by resolving the `www.domain.com` host, then sending a request to that host.

Thus, you've got a browsing history for `http://domain.com`, then `http://www.domain.com`.

Comment: I am getting this behavior in all browser except chrome, I have upgraded firefox only, but why I am getting this behavior now I have written this code months ago, I didn't see any such thing then. also I have not seen this kind of behavior with any other site with same 301 redirect for example `http://cnet.com/` is redirected to `http://www.cnet.com/` and there is only one redirected url in browser history in same browser.